# Apply Today to my time field in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

In my data table, I have a column called window. 
[image]

For example, the last 5 characters for first row in window is 06:29, which means
(it is today's data) 6/26/2018 6:29:00 AM.

I am using:

```
to_date(SUBSTR(WINDOW,7,5),'hh24,mi') as Date_Fomt
```

trying to covert it to what I need 6/26/2018 6:29:00 AM. But as you can see, I return the first day of current month, so what should I do to apply today'day, which is 6/26/2018 to my time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the date part, this could be a way:

```
to_date( to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy ') || SUBSTR(WINDOW,7,5),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24,mi')
```